# Adding to JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have tried everything and it is probably very simple to solve. I want to add to a JSON object. I have searched and found examples but it does not yield the results I want. I have a JSON object that looks like this

```
{"d86":"2020-03-04","d76":"2020-03-05"}
```

Now I want to append to this so it looks like this

```
{"d86":"2020-03-04","d76":"2020-03-05","d97":"2020-05-08"}
```

The examples of how to do this give me this result

```
{"d86":"2020-03-04","d76":"2020-03-05","0":{"d97":"2020-03-08"}}
```

This is my code:

```
$j = array('d86'=>'2020-03-04','d76'=>'2020-03-05');

$j = json_encode($j);

$j = json_decode($j, true);

$new_date = array('d97'=>'2020-03-08');

$j[] = $new_date;

$j = json_encode($j);

print_r($j);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just "add" the `$new_date` to the existing array:

```
$j += $new_date;
```

Output:

```
{
    "d86": "2020-03-04",
    "d76": "2020-03-05",
    "d97": "2020-03-08"
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/XFgZS)

Comment: brilliant, how i missed this one :)

Comment: Nice. I did not think you can treat an array like a string.

Comment: @MSC you're not really treating it as a string, `+` is a defined operator for arrays: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple rows to add

you could use `foreach` to be like this

```
foreach($new_date as $key => $value){
    $j[$key] = $value;
}
```

so it will be like this one

```
$j = array('d86'=>'2020-03-04','d76'=>'2020-03-05');

$j = json_encode($j);

$j = json_decode($j, true);

$new_date = ['d97'=>'2020-03-08'];

foreach($new_date as $key => $value){
    $j[$key] = $value;
}

$j = json_encode($j);

print_r($j);
```